# DenseNet121 (PyTorch) : On the BatchNorm2d and Global Average Pooling layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, max-pooling

Running the following code

```
from torchvision import models
dnet121 = models.densenet121(pretrained = True)
dnet121
```

yields a DenseNet121 description which ends as follows :
[image]

Based on this, I would appreciate your assistance of the following:

- As per PyTorch BatchNorm2d documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html the BatchNorm2d transform accepts a 4-dim tensor (here with channels C=1024) and outputs a 4-dim tensor. But, as per above image, how does the output 4-dim tensor convert to the 1024 in_features of the Linear layer ? Is it due to a Global Average Pooling layer ?

  As per DenseNet official paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf the classifier starts indeed with a Global Average Pooling (GAP) layer, but why can't we see it here?
- For the purposes of a task, I would like to replace the GAP layer with a nn.Flatten layer. How can I get code access to the GAP layer though?

Comment: The DenseNet article only mentions "Global Average Pool" twice from what Ctrl+F shows me and the article notes "At the end of the last dense block, a global average pooling is performed and then a softmax classifier is attached." // Also, please copy-paste the entire model summary. // If need be, build your own `DenseNet` directly by subclassing or reusing `DenseNet` from `torchvision` source: https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/models/densenet.html

Comment: You are right. Also in the first mention of Ctrl+F, in table 1, the layer is shown in the beginning of the Classification layer. In both cases though the layer isn't visible in the code description. No idea why. // Sadly i can not paste the entire summary as my post would exceed the 30000 characters limit. Also it doesn't fit to any image. // Thank you. I will try that.